# SSO in .net core application authentication against external customer's azure accounts

Tags: c#, .net-core, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I need to add SSO into an existing asp.net framework application that is hosted on an IIS server on AWS. This application is used by a number of different customers and they each have their own instance of the application on the IIS server. I have been looking into this, and I think I am going to create a new .net core application that will handle the SSO side of things and then redirect to the application once the authentication has been confirmed. I only need to set up authentication, as the application handles what the users can and can't do. I have used the following you tube tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S_xDAB_s-GM - and have come across an issue which I have been unable to find a suitable answer for. As this application will be used by multiple customers, they will have their own AD server that will be used to Authorise the user against, every example I can find is for setup for an internal application only, using the internal AD, and using configuration set in the appsettings.json file. I was wondering if anyone has any pointers as to how I can add the setting up of the AD details as an admin function in my application that writes the values to a table in a database, for example, so that the configuration can be done by the customer and they can then use their AD for the authentication?

Comment: are your customers using on-prem AD or Azure AD in the cloud?

Comment: Sorry for slow reply, I have been on holiday. It will be the customer on-premise AD.